# How to get those row where a field value exist in all foreign key type from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Resource Table
id  resource_id resource_name
1   3             address
2   3             company
3   5             phone
4   3             phone
```

I have a table like following. Here i use resource_id as foreign key. I want to find only those field value which are exist in all resource_id type.

for example, field value phone exist in all resource_id define here (3,5) but value company and address exist only one resource_id. so i need to extract only phone.

How can i write a mysql query to accomplish this task efficiently

Comment: can you show the result which you want?

Comment: What are the names of the other tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(resource_id) AS cnt, 
       resource_name 
FROM   the_table 
GROUP  BY resource_name 
HAVING cnt = (SELECT Count(DISTINCT resource_id) 
              FROM   the_table);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from resource
group by resource_name
having count(resource_name)>1
```

Comment: I am not donw voter but your suggestion won't work if there are 3 resourceId for some name. Your query will return the ones with 2 of 3 resources

Comment: You mean to say that for name(phone) ids are (3,5,6) fro example

Comment: Yes. phone (3,5,6) and address (3, 5). Your query returns address but must be phone only